# How to click hidden button for Atata framework?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, atata

There is a clickable button that is hidden in a part of the project I'm doing. It becomes visible when the mouse is over it. I want to click the hidden button. I tried most of the methods written in the web site but I have not been successful. Do you have any suggestions?

```
<div class="btn-group" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <a class="btn btn-xs" title="Add" onclick="AddAction()">
    <i clas="fa fa-plus-circle test-success"> == $0
      ::before
    </i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't post code as image please.

Comment: Where are your code attempts? You should be able to hover the element and then click it once it becomes visible. Try that and post your code and the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, though you are using `visibility: hidden`, I would recommend using `opacity` instead. This still hides the button as you would expect. Feel free to look into the [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com) website. It has a lot of great resources that cover simple things like this.

I utilized the following references from that site:

[onclick Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

[onmouseover Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)

[onmouseout Event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)

[opacity Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp)

```js
function OnHover(element) {
      element.style.opacity = 100;
    }
    function OnExit(element) {
      element.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    function OnClick(element) {
      element.innerHTML = "You clicked me as a hidden button!";
      element.style.color = "red";
    }
```

```css
.btn {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.btn:hover {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnO" onmouseover="OnHover(this)" onmouseout="OnExit(this)" onclick="OnClick(this)" style="opacity: 0;">Opacity</button>
<button id="btnV" onclick="OnClick(this)" class="btn">Visibility</button>
```

I believe since [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) has been set to `hidden` in your scenario, the page doesn't fire the events wired into the element. Even [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) such as `hover` seem to be impacted by this property. It doesn't appear to reduce the size of the element, as changing an element's `visibility` via developer tools in live time doesn't affect the layout of the page. However, `opacity` simply reduces the alpha channel on the element and all events are still fired off as normal.

More senior web developers; feel free to correct me if I'm wrong in the above statement. I couldn't find much documentation on this.

> Tip: Hidden elements take up space on the page. Use the display property to both hide and remove an element from the document layout!

With respect to the quote above from W3 Schools, you could create an empty `div` element that houses your button. Then, when the user hovers over the `div` element display the button or call a javascript function from the `onclick` event. In which case you could use the `visibility` property as you wouldn't be directly interacting with the button, but rather the `div`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the intent of the question. OP is trying to write Selenium automation to hover and then click the element once it becomes available. His lack of script/example code probably didn't help readers understand his intent was not to do web development but to write automation.